# How to run a function every month in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, function

I want to make a website where every month a fixed amount will increase in student's database. I want that i'll write a function and the function will run every first day of a month

I Want to Add a certain amount of fees to be added in every individual student account every month.
To do that, I need to run a function in the 1st day of month. How do I run a function continuously after every month?

Comment: To be clear: the program runs continuously, 24/7, and you want it to check the time and run a function once per real-world, calendar month? Or do you want to *start up a new program* once per month? or just what? Also, what does this have to do with Django?

Comment: Have you tried looking into cronjobs (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/)? You can also set a thread on a timer for repetitive tasks

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I want to make a website where every month a fixed amount will increase in their database. So I need to add fees automatically by a function. I want that i'll write a function and the function will run every first day of a month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a solution by searching here and there...
I need a package to be installed and then that'll do the job!!

[Here's the link for that answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62525730/14765479)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a function that's triggered on an hourly basis would be a good idea. Scheduled jobs/tasks, like adding monthly fees, are good candidates for this.

You could also look into cron jobs, which would be useful if you're on a Linux server, or task scheduler for Windows.

Here's a decent tutorial on how to make timer triggered cloud functions with AWS:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents-tutorial.html